# Fixing errors in JasperReport

Tags: java, html, report

I need some help with JasperReport, here is my template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport
  PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
  "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport name="HelloReportWorld">
    <parameter name="reportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="author" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="startDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

```
<field name="CUSTOMER_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="STATE" class="java.lang.String"/>


<title>
    <band height="60">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="500" height="40"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
            <font size="24"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$P(reportTitle)]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="500" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment = "Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA["Ejecutado por: " + $P(author) +
                " on " + $P(startDate)]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="30">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="500" height="25"/>
            <graphicElement/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="50" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="55" y="5" width="250" height="15"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Nombre]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="205" y="5" width="255" height="15"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Ciudad, Estado]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P(CUSTOMER_ID)]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="55" y="0" width="150" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P(NAME)]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P(CITY) + ", " + $P(STATE)]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>

    </band>
</detail>
```

Here is the main class:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author alejandro
 */
public class JAsperDemo1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String reportSource = "./reports/templates/HolaMundo.jrxml";
        String reportDest = "./reports/results/HolaMundo.html";


        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("reportTitle", "Informe Hola Mundo");
        params.put("author", "Jose Javier Ber");
        params.put("startDate",(new java.util.Date()).toString());

        try
        {
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

            java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample", "app", "app");


            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, conn);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        }catch(JRException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

and those are the errors Im getting:

> Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:183:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PRODUCT_ID); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PRODUCT_ID   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:188:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(DESCRIPTION); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable DESCRIPTION   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:193:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PURCHASE_COST); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PURCHASE_COST   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:256:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PRODUCT_ID); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PRODUCT_ID   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:261:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(DESCRIPTION); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable DESCRIPTION   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:266:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PURCHASE_COST); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PURCHASE_COST   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:329:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PRODUCT_ID); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PRODUCT_ID   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:334:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(DESCRIPTION); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable DESCRIPTION   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732
>   C:\Users\alejandro\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JasperDemo\HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732.java:339:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                   value = $F(PURCHASE_COST); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
>                              ^   symbol:   variable PURCHASE_COST   location: class HelloReportWorld_1460420530440_343732 9 errors

Comment: You should at least explain where you think the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you must put:
**$P{reportTitle}**
not
**$P(reportTitle)**